# Writing Python Script to get equal name as given and compare to multiple shp file in folder and copy selected shp file to new folder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap

Need to go through multi shp file in a folder and copy a single feature which has the same name as entry to the new folder with staying same name and format. I create a piece of python code that can go through each shp file and also can to the output folder but, I can’t get any output. Any suggestion or concern please.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import os
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
Match_FC='Feature_Compare_01'
env.workspace =r'C:\Users\OutputTool\LineData\Separated Parcels'
output=r'C:\Users\Desktop\New Folder'
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

# Copy shapefiles to N folder-After looking with -9 characters 
for fc in fcList:
  if fc[-9:]==Match_FC:
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(fc, output,'{}_new'.format(fc))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing two lines of code at the beginning of your `for` loop to make sure that you are getting the values that you think you are.

```
for fc in fcList:
  print fc
  print fc[-9:]
  if fc[-9:]==Match_FC:
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(fc, output,'{}_new'.format(fc))
```

Also, somewhere during Python 2.x, and ArcPy 10.x used several dot releases of Python 2.x, the syntax for `'{}_new'.format()` became available.  Prior to that you had to explicitly number the tokens i.e. `'{0}_new'.format()` will work at more versions.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I used print function and the result was including ".shp" and I added [-13:-3] to the script then work as i wanted, but there is a problem. It look like doesn't stop after it find the related shp file and running the scripts for long time. could you please let me know how can I add break to stop after the script find the related shp file with correct name and copy it to the folder. Thx

Comment: @Koush That sounds like a different question.  I recommend seeing if you can solve it first, and if not, then see if you can create a test snippet that demonstrates just that problem to present as a new question.

Comment: I added a break command after copy and creating FC and it works great. Thx